Why is my pywin32gui/PIL function not returning an image generated from a bitmap like I expect, but rather a completely black image?
I have this function in my code, which is supposed to generate a bitmap from an application and convert that to an image using Pillow. Whenever I save the output, though, it only returns a black image. The image is always in the correct dimensions.
The function:
def screenshot(window_title):
    hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, window_title)
    hwnd_dc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
    mfc_dc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hwnd_dc)
    save_dc = mfc_dc.CreateCompatibleDC()
    save_bit_map = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    region = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
    save_bit_map.CreateCompatibleBitmap(mfc_dc, abs(region[0]-region[2]), abs(region[1]-region[3]))
    save_dc.SelectObject(save_bit_map)
    bmp_info = save_bit_map.GetInfo()
    bmp_str = save_bit_map.GetBitmapBits(True)
    img = Image.frombuffer('RGB',
                           (bmp_info['bmWidth'], bmp_info['bmHeight']),
                           bmp_str, 'raw', 'BGRX', 0, 1)
    win32gui.DeleteObject(save_bit_map.GetHandle())
    save_dc.DeleteDC()
    mfc_dc.DeleteDC()
    win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, hwnd_dc)
    return img.convert('RGB')

I'm saving the output from this directly to a file. In the future, I want to use it with pytesseract for OCR.
Any help is appreciated.

You have created a bitmap in memory that matches the bit depth and dimensions of your window, and then associated it with the window - but you've done absolutely nothing to cause the window contents to be drawn into the bitmap, so a solid black image seems like the expected result.  The step you're missing is to call BitBlt().
